# Como pegar o valor de $_GET['selcionados'] para deixar o checkbox selecionado usando PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, replace

Tenho uma array em PHP que são os valores selecionados do checkbox, que foram obtidos pelo $_GET:

```
$_GET['selecionados'] = array(2) { 
[0]=> string(1) "a" 
[1]=> string(1) "b"  
}
```

Aí tenho os chekboxes:

```
foreach($selecoes = $check){
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$check->valor.'" name="selecionados[]" id="'.$check->valor.'">
}
```

ele imprime:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" name="selecionados[]" id="a">
<input type="checkbox" value="b" name="selecionados[]" id="b">
<input type="checkbox" value="c" name="selecionados[]" id="c">
<input type="checkbox" value="d" name="selecionados[]" id="d">
```

Eu preciso que se o valor de selecionados estiver no $_GET['selecionados'], ele fique como marcado "checked". nesse exemplo ficaria:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="a" name="selecionados[]" id="a" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="b" name="selecionados[]" id="b" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="c" name="selecionados[]" id="c">
<input type="checkbox" value="d" name="selecionados[]" id="d">
```

Como fazer? Imagino que seja usando o str_replace, mas não sei exatamente como.

Comment: pq escrevi errado...rs, os valores são c e d, estou alterando a pergunta...

Comment: Você jã descreveu a lógica: se estiver em `$_GET['selecionados']` adiciona `checked`. Como tentou implementar isso?

Comment: os que tentei não deu certo. tentei usar echo str_replace('id="'.$_GET['selecionados'].'"', 'id="'.$_GET['selecionados'].'" checked', $opcao) ( o $opcao declarei como '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$check->valor.'" name="selecionados[]" id="'.$check->valor.'">'

Comment: Poem na pergunta as tentativas e os resultados de cada uma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode dentro do foreach que mostra os checkbox, verificar se o valor está no array $_GET['selecionados'], o código ficaria assim:

```
foreach($selecoes as $check){
  $checked = (in_array($check->valor, $_GET['selecionados']))?'checked':'';
  echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$check->valor.'" name="selecionados[]" id="'.$check->valor.'" '.$checked.'>';
}
```

A função in_array() verifica se o valor existe em aluma posição do array, então se existir ele marca como checked.

Comment: tentei mas deu erro, no meio do echo vc está abrindo o "<?" acho q aí que deu erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in

Comment: Exatamente, acabei descuidando e não vi que estava dentro do echo, agora esta OK.

Comment: Também editei seu foreach, onde estava `$selecoes = $check` troquei o `=` por `as`, era ele quem estava gerando seu erro.

Comment: perfeito, isso q ia falar...rs, agora deu certinho, só pra entender, o in_array ve se o $check->valor está dentro do $check->valor, aí se tiver ele imprime checked?

Comment: Isso, o in_array() verifica se o `$check->valor` está no array `$_GET['selecionados']`, se quiser pode [ver a documentação aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).